# What to prefer namespace or static functions in c++

Tags: c++

If a class does not have a state, should we include it in a namespace or make static functions instead. Namespaces cant have private functions though classes can. For example:

**Approach 1:**

```
class Algorithms
{
    static double calculate_bearing();

    private:
            static double function_used_by_calculate_bearing_function();
};
```

**Approach 2:**

```
namespace Algorithms
    {
        double calculate_bearing();
    
        namespace __Internal
        {
            double function_used_by_calculate_bearing_function();
        }
    }
```

What approach is preferable among two?

Comment: Namespaces and classes serve different purposes. Namespaces are for avoiding name conflicts between libraries. Classes are for packaging related functionality.

Comment: Agreed. But in above mentioned case, what would you do. I just want to know other people's point of view.

Comment: `namespace __Internal` seems like a really nasty code smell.

Comment: Questions asking for opinions are specifically off-topic on [so].

Comment: Names containing double underscores like `__Internal` are reserved for the implementation. Don't use them, or you might get obscure errors from accidentally redefining something in the standard library. "Each name that contains a double underscore (__) or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.11) is reserved to the implementation for any use." [C++ 2003 standard 17.4.3.1.2].

Comment: Thanks  Pascal Getreuer. It was just an example. I don't use standard names otherwise.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the link. I did not know about the other site.

Comment: @Barmar I disagree that namespaces are only "for avoiding name conflicts between libraries" and that "Classes are for packaging related functionality". That kind of statement encourages uses of classes when there is no need to use them, and leads to the over-OOP-ification of the language and design. Namespaces are very well usable as an organisational tool, and I would encourage people to try using them as such when possible.

Comment: @underscore_d Those are their main uses. And I didn't say that when you have related functionality you always use classes, but when you use classes that's normally what they're for. Classes should reflect a consistent "thing" in your domain.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a fan of using `class` + `static` to emulate `namespace`. It's a workaround for a different language's limitations.

In this case however, I'd go for option 3, omitting the forward declaration and defining it with [internal linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces).

algorithms.hpp

```
namespace Algorithms
{
    double calculate_bearing();
}
```

algorithms.cpp

```
namespace
{
    double function_used_by_calculate_bearing_function() { /* some calculation */ }
}

namespace Algorithms
{
    double calculate_bearing() { /* use above function */ }
}
```

Comment: hanks @Caleth...